# How to use variable in php array read from file

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to use a variable in an array that has been read from a file. This is what I have thus far and it is returning the variable name instead of the value. The example intentionally does not have a space between $var.doe and saint.$var AND places the $var in front of "doe" and behind "saint" because that is the actual data we are dealing with. Thank you for your help.

read.txt

```
$var.doe
saint.$var
```

php file

```
<?
$var = "john";
$aArray = file('read.txt');
echo $aArray[0];
echo '<br>';
echo $aArray[1];
?>
```

Comment: Maybe because it is a string?!

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: probably you can use $$ if they are local variables

Comment: Rizier123 - the expected output would be johndoe and saintjoe

Comment: 1. You don't have a space here: `$var.doe` how do you define, that the variable only goes until the dot? 2. Why does the other `$var` evaluates as something different than the first `$var` ?! Makes no sense at all.

Comment: Rizier123 - It's just an example, you can configure it however you want. The goal is to get $var to echo the value "john"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to substitute the variables:

```
php > $s = '
$var.doe
saint.$var
';
php > echo $s;

$var.doe
saint.$var
php > $var = 'jone';
php > echo str_replace('$var', $var, $s);

john.doe
saint.john
```

Comment: Thank you Cez, str_replace() solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You must do something like this :
read.txt

```
doe
saint
```

php file

```
<?php
   $var = "john";
   $aArray = file('read.txt');
   echo $var." ".$aArray[0];
   echo $aArray[1]." ".$var;
?>
```

all the variable must be on the php file and all the string must be on the txt file.